# Is the CSS3 keyframe at 100% inclusive?

Tags: animation, webkit, css

When creating continuous animations in CSS3, such as an infinite rotation, is the keyframe at 100% inclusive? That is, are the properties given at 100% set at the last frame of the current iteration?

An example: would a glow animation using

```
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
    50%  { opacity: 0.7; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

cause a slight (and possibly imperceptible) lag due to two consecutive frames with an opacity of 1?

Comment: I perceive lag in the pulse animation described [in this webkit.org article](http://webkit.org/blog/324/css-animation-2).

Answer (score 1):

The current state of CSS3 animation is that many of them have a small but perceptible stutter particularly if they repeat too quickly. To mitigate this, make your animation longer with more keyframes aka

```css
0%     { opacity 1; }
5%     { opacity .7; }
10%    { opacity 1; }
15%    { opacity .7; }
20%    { opacity 1; }
```

etc.

Comment: Okey, is there any documentation on this? I haven't been able to find any!

Comment: welcome to the bleeding edge of web development. there is practically no documentation on CSS Animations - you get to discover things :-) If you want to play around with Animations - you can always try our product - Sencha Animator (now in early alpha)

Answer (score 1):

But mostly, your problem here is due to the easing which is by default `ease-in-out`, meaning it will focus more on the style of 0% and 100% of your animation. So it will be mainly very close to `opacity:1`.

For this kind of animation you can also use alternate, so you'll have only 2 keyframes.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0.5; }
}

.glow {
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @micky2be, but it's not really the topic of the question!